# Display numeric code as string value

Tags: sql-server, select

SQL statement that queries database of 3rd party software

```
SELECT dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,dbo.SEM_AGENT.STATUS ('1' = ONLINE, '0' = offline)
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
```

The value of `dbo.SEM_AGENT.STATUS` is either `'1'` for online, or `'0'` for offline.

How to specify this in a `SELECT` Statement because the above statement gives error.

## UPDATE

When I searched google for "sql convert number into words", all I got was how to convert the number 15000 into fifteen thousand with some complex SQL code that is not needed right now. Hence, I posted this question.

Comment: try to see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070153/how-to-use-a-case-statement-in-scalar-valued-function-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,  
   CASE dbo.SEM_AGENT.STATUS 
       WHEN 0 THEN 'Offline'
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Online'
   END
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

A case statement would do the trick here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx