# Multiple Case Statements - Function/Sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wish to create a table with many fields. And I need to do multiple case statement on each field. Please help me with a clean way (Function/Stored Proc) to do it, instead of writing case statement over and over.

Below is an example SQL.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'XXX' THEN 'YYY' ELSE NULL END,
         CASE WHEN Col1 IN ('AAA','BBB') AND Col2 IS NULL THEN 'ZZZ' ELSE NULL END,
         CASE WHEN Col1 = 'CCC' THEN 'DDD' ELSE Col2 END ) AS col_i
  .
  .
  .

FROM table
```

Comment: Those are case _expressions_ (since they return a value.)

Comment: Can you suggest any other clean way to implement

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about. If you keep finding yourself in need to apply the same big `case` expression every time you select data from a certain table, create a [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with that `select` as use it instead.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SalmanA The question I ask myself every day I wake up to keep going to work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a single query, you can use `apply` (or a subquery or CTE):

```
SELECT v.col_i
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE . . . )
     ) v(col_i)
```

If you want this generally available, then don't use a function, use a computed column:

```
alter table t add col_i as
     (case . . . );
```

This would then be available to anyone using the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can rewrite your logic into a single `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN Col1 = 'XXX'
     THEN 'YYY'
     WHEN Col1 IN ('AAA', 'BBB') AND Col2 IS NULL
     THEN 'ZZZ'
     WHEN Col1 = 'CCC'
     THEN 'DDD'
     ELSE Col2 END
```

What makes this work is that your `ELSE` values are `NULL` (except for the very last `CASE` expression), which logically means that `COALESCE` would just rollover to the next `CASE` expression.

Comment: Thanks but can i call the  case function itself from a function or sproc?

Comment: See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070153/how-to-use-a-case-statement-in-scalar-valued-function-in-sql) to see how to use a `CASE` expression in a scalar valued function.  Not sure about procs.